# IF statement not working - Any suggestions?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, cookies

So I have a function which counts the amount of customer orders.

I want to show a congratulations modal that appears when a customer hits a specific amount of orders.

All of my code is working fine, except when I add this part to the IF statement:

`|| in_array($count, $the_digits) && isset( $_COOKIE['tier_advance'] ) && $_COOKIE['tier_advance'] !== $count )`

The cookie is being saved properly, and when saved the number is saved as the current value of `count`. The idea is that the modal will only show if:

A) their current count is in `$the_digits` array & the cookie is not set.
B) their current count is in `$the_digits` array & the cookie IS set, however the cookies value does not equal their current order `$count` amount.

This is to prevent the modal showing after the initial display, but still allow it to show again if they hit the next `$count` amount to move to the next tier.

Can't figure out what is wrong. Or perhaps there is a better way to do this. All help appreciated.

```
        $the_digits = ['3','5','15','30','50'];

        if ( in_array($count, $the_digits) && !isset( $_COOKIE[ 'tier_advance' ] ) || in_array($count, $the_digits) && isset( $_COOKIE['tier_advance'] ) && $_COOKIE['tier_advance'] !== $count )  {
        echo'
            
            <script>
                    jQuery(window).on("load",function(){
                        jQuery("#tier_advance").modal("show");
                    });
                    jQuery(document).on("click", "#tier_confirm", function(){            
                        // Set a cookie
                        Cookies.set("tier_advance", "' . $count . '", { expires: 356 });
                    });

            </script>
            
            <!-- BEGIN Share Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="tier_advance" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h5>CONGRATULATIONS!</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body text-center">
                  <p>You are now a <strong class="all-caps"> ' . $tier_name . ' </strong>tier customer!</p>
                  <p>Expect some dope rewards to start coming your way!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer modal-footer-centered">
                    <button id="tier_confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Awesome, thanks!</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Share Modal -->';

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with that huge statement with lots of && and || then it's a good idea to simplify it. To refactor your code a bit to make it more understandable (and so you can figure it out you when you look at it in 2 years) you could do something like this:

Before:

```
    if ( in_array($count, $the_digits) && !isset( $_COOKIE[ 'tier_advance' ] ) || in_array($count, $the_digits) && isset( $_COOKIE['tier_advance'] ) && $_COOKIE['tier_advance'] !== $count )
```

After:

```
    $showModal = false;

    if (in_array($count, $the_digits)) {
        if (!isset( $_COOKIE[ 'tier_advance' ] )) {
            $showModal= true;
        } else {
            if ($_COOKIE['tier_advance'] !== $count) {
                $showModal = true;
            } else {
                // echo "false because tier_advance !== count
            }
        } 
    } else {
        // echo "false because not in the_digits";
    }

    if ($showModal) {
          // do the thing
    }
```

Although this is much longer, it's much easier to understand the logic **and** it allows you to add some debug statements to it so you can see at what point it set to true/false to debug. I put a couple of echo's in there as examples, but obviously if you can use logging functionality that's better.

EDIT: I just noticed that you're using `!==` which as you may know does a type check as well as an equality check. I think in this case the cookie might always be a string, so you should try this with just `!=` instead.

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach, thank you! I need to start writing cleaner code.

However, it still seems to not recognize the value of the Cookie and act accordingly... no idea why

Comment: I just noticed that the equality check on the cookie might have something to do with it. Oh, and that you've also noticed this is another answer, heh.

Comment: I was not aware of that! So ``!==`` equates to ``is not or is equal to`` whereas ``!=`` equates to ``is not equal to``? That is a huge lesson I just learned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

```
$_COOKIE["tier_advance"] !== "$count")
```

Note the quotations on the variable. Cookies are saved as strings, therefore without the quotations it was ringing true.

Thanks to @mozboz for cleaning it up and making this more apparent for me.